# Is the fuselage of the CEA 311 Anequim configured as elliptical?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, feature-identification, fuselage

I am currently studying the effects of reduced drag induced by laminar flow on the subsonic aircraft. In order to complete that, I have believed I found the optimal fuselage which has the best favorable pressure gradient. This fuselage is the NACA 66, which looks like an elliptical format.

Now I am here to ask you guys,

[image]

Is this CAE 311 fuselage elliptical?

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you want laminar flow over the forward fuselage, remove the propeller.

The wake of the propeller will trip flow immediately. Laminarisation is the reason for the fixed front part of the canopy on some gliders: Along the gap between the moveable canopy and the fuselage a wedge of turbulent flow develops which can only be avoided by a very smooth and gapless surface.

[image: DG-100 forward fuselage]

DG-100 forward fuselage (picture [source](https://alchetron.com/Glaser-Dirks-DG-100)). The two-part canopy was inspired by the hope of keeping flow laminar. Later versions changed to a single-piece canopy.

To answer your question: In my understanding the "elliptical" in elliptical fuselage refers to its cross section, not the profile in side view. Except for the two side bubbles of the canopy, your design has indeed an elliptical fuselage.